# DRY Principles. Is this too DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

Been following the DRY principles and trying not to repeat my code where possible and thus reusing controller actions and views.

I have used the index.html.erb view for my Listings on the main page which you can see here http://frnsh.herokuapp.com/

Then reused this view to show only listings by a certain User/Vendor
http://frnsh.herokuapp.com/vendors/2/listings

This is great as I have remained DRY and reused the index.html.erb

However I would like to display that User/Vendor's bio and ultimately a logo of theirs when you follow the link and head here http://frnsh.herokuapp.com/vendors/2/listings

Is this possible or should I have really created a vendor.html.erb page? If it is possible to stay DRY how would I go about customising the index.html.erb view?

My index.html.erb is as follows:

```
<div class="center">
 <div class="row">
   <% @listings.each do |listing| %>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <%= link_to image_tag(listing.image.url), listing %>

  <div class="caption">
    <h3><%= listing.name %></h3>
    <p><%= link_to listing.user.name, vendor_listings_path(:vendor_id => listing.user.to_param) %></p>
    <p><%= number_to_currency(listing.price, :unit => "£") %></p>
    <p><%= listing.user.bio %></p>
  </div>
 </div>

 </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

My controller is also below in case that is required:

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:seller, :new, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
 before_filter :set_vendor, only: [:index]

def seller
  @listings = Listing.where(user: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
end

def index
 @listings  = @vendor.present? ? @vendor.listings : Listing.all
 @listings  = @listings.order("created_at DESC")
end

def show
end

def new
 @listing = Listing.new
end


 def edit
 end


 def create
   @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
   @listing.user_id = current_user.id

 respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.save
    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end


 def update
   respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.update(listing_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end

def destroy
 @listing.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to listings_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

Comment: I didn't go through your controller or view code but to comment on your question, could you not introduce a partial and render that upon a condition/flag.  The flag could be set in the controller.  Or, you could also define a helper for the extra info.

Answer (score 3):

I think your question of `is it too DRY?` is *really* `is it right?`

---

**Structure**

The reason I write this is because if you look at what you've created - you need to call that `index` partial every time you call the respective controller actions you want to use it on.

This is important because when you have an application, from a development perspective at least, you need to ensure you have a *flow* which is both intuitive & extensible. The *risk* you run with using a partial as you have, is that you will have to maintain the same structure / interface every time you call it

Whilst not a problem, it will become very restrictive each time you create new actions -- a core aspect of your question I think (when you didn't know how to add the different styling options to your `listings` objects)

--

**Objects**

I've been writing this a lot, but I think it's apt for you too - **Rails is [object orientated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)**. This means that if you want to create a partial, you'd be much better suited to using your controller / action views as you would normally; applying partials to specific *objects*:

```
#app/views/shared/_listing.html.erb #-> partial
<%= link_to listing.name, listing %>


#app/views/application/index.html.erb #-> root path
<%= render "shared/listing", collection: @listings, as: "listing" %>

#app/views/listings/index.html.erb
<%= render "shared/listing", collection: @listings, as: "listing" %>

#app/views/listings/show.html.erb
<%= render "shared/listing", object: @listing %>
```

Although a very simplified demonstration, what I'm trying to give you is the idea that if you [break up your partials to display objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials), you'll be able to craft a much more [modular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) flow

I think the current issue you have is that you are treating the `partial` as part of your layout, and consequently hitting some [antipatterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern#Software_engineering). Really, you should use it to display specific objects, which you can then tailor around your layout

Answer (score 1):

It's not too DRY. In fact, you can DRY it up some more by moving everything in the `@listings.each` block to a listing partial and then rendering that partial. Rails provides a shorthand syntax for that which would be, `render @listings` which will loop through the collection for you.

Based on your `ListingsController` code, I'm going to assume that the "/" (home page) URL and "/vendors/2/listings" URL both route to the listings#index action, which displays listings/index.html.erb. This means that the problem you're trying to solve is, how to show the vendor information in listings/index.html.erb based on whether or not the vendor is passed. To do that, create a vendor partial that has the vendor information you want to display when the vendor is present. Then render the vendor using `<%= render @vendor %>`. If `@vendor` is missing, `render` will return `nil` and nothing will be displayed, otherwise the contents of the partial will be displayed.

Rails guides are great for more information about partials: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html